# Property isn't serialized

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, properties

```
        [XmlIgnore()]
        public List<MyObject> ListMyObjects = new List<MyObject>();
        public List<string> MyProperty
        {
            get
            {
                List<string> list = new List<string>();
                foreach (MyObject obj in ListMyObjects)
                    list.Add(obj.Name);
                return list;
            }
            set
            {
                foreach (string name in value)
                    ListMyObjects.Add(new MyObject(name));
            }
        }
```

Why is MyPropery not serializing? I am using Xml Serializer.

Comment: Can you provide more information? What kind of serializer are you using? Xml? Data Contract, Binary?

Comment: @PhilBolduc I am using XMl Serializer

Comment: What happens when it tries to serialize? Do either of the accessors get called? I would actually expect that work (although I'd probably have a Clear() in the "set", too)

Comment: Collections will not serialize due to generics unless you are using XAML Serialization, but an array will, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody please format my code, it isn't formating on iPad.

Please try this,

```
public string[] MyProperty
        {
            get
            {
                List<string> list = new List<string>();
                foreach (MyObject obj in ListMyObjects)
                    list.Add(obj.Name);
                return list.ToArray();
            }
            set
            {
                foreach (string name in value)
                    ListMyObjects.Add(new MyObject(name));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me.. Check this..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace Serialization_Xml
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Data data = new Data();
            List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
            mylist.Add("A");
            mylist.Add("B");
            data.MyProperty = mylist;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("Data.xml", FileMode.Create);
            XmlSerializer serializer= new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
            serializer.Serialize(fs, data);
        }
    }

   public class Data
    {
        [XmlIgnore()]
        public List<MyObject> ListMyObjects = new List<MyObject>();
        public List<string> MyProperty
        {
            get
            {
                List<string> list = new List<string>();
                foreach (MyObject obj in ListMyObjects)
                    list.Add(obj.Name);
                return list;
            }
            set
            {
                foreach (string name in value)
                    ListMyObjects.Add(new MyObject(name));
            }
        }

    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public string Name;
        public MyObject(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MyProperty>
    <string>A</string>
    <string>B</string>
  </MyProperty>
</Data>
```